# Read error looking for ack: read tcp 10.11.12.13:1223 i/o timeout in logstash-forwarder

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-forwarder

I've setup the logstash. All of sudden the logstash-forwarder stops to send the logs to Logstash. While checking the logs, its show the below error, can anyone help me to fix this ?

```
Read error looking for ack: read tcp 10.11.12.13:1223 i/o timeout
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The error shows there is no connection between logstash forwarder (or client) to logstash indexer (or server). Common reasons:

1. Logstash service is down on logstash indexer. If down, start the service up.
2. connection between logstash forwarder and indexer is blocked by firewall.

How to check?

```
login forwarder
telnet 10.11.12.13 1223
```

If you can't, that's the firewall issue. You need fix or rollback some recent changes.

Comment: There is no network issue. While checking the logstash indexer log, noticed the below error message.

:message=>"A plugin had an unrecoverable error. Will restart this plugin.\n  Plugin: <LogStash::Inputs::Lumberjack type=>\"logs\", ssl_certificate=>\"/etc/pki/tls/certs/test.crt\", ssl_key=>\"/etc/pki/tls/private/test.key\", host=>\"0.0.0.0\">\n  Error: Java heap space", :level=>:error}